# Laragon and phpmyadmin, allow access outside

Tags: phpmyadmin, laragon

I have laragon 3.4 and latest phpmyadmin. Everything works well with localhost but I want to access to phpmyadmin through local network.

How can I do that with laragon ? I can't find something to put "allow from all".

I don't know if it's important but I have mysql on port 3307 and my site on port 84.

When I try to access to my ip/phpmyadmin I have a 403 error.

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Furya: For security, Laragon only allows access phpMyAdmin from localhost by default.
You can change that behavior by editing this file:
`C:\laragon\etc\apache2\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

Just change '**Require local**' to '**Require all granted**'.